# How do I get the months to match up with the correct inputed number?

Tags: java, arrays

Java
How do I get the months to match up with the correct inputed number?
Hello, when I print the statements for the month with the lowest and highest precipitation, the months do not match the numbers. The numbers for the least and highest amounts are correct but the month doesn't correspond. Thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class rain{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    Double a[] = new Double[12];
    int year = 0;
    String city = "";
    String[] eachMonth = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
    double lowest = 50.0;
    int lowestIndex = -1;
    double highest = 0.0;
    int highestIndex = -1;
    double sum = 0;
    double average = 0;
    double totalPrecipitation = sum;
    int feet = 0;
    int inches = 0;


    System.out.println("Enter city name");
    city = scanner.next();

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter four digit number between 1900 and 2025 ");// prompt user for height in feet
        year = scanner.nextInt();
        if (year < 1900 || year > 2025) {
            System.out.println("Error invalid input enter number between 190 and 2025"); //must be positive whole number of tickets
        }
    } while (year < 1900 || year > 2025);

    System.out.println("Enter the precipitation for the following months ");

    double inputVal;
    for (int monthCount = 0; monthCount < eachMonth.length; monthCount++) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.print(eachMonth[monthCount].concat(" : "));

            inputVal = scanner.nextDouble();
            if (inputVal > 50.0 || inputVal < 0.0)
                System.out.println("Please enter value in the range [0.0-50.0]");
            else {
                a[monthCount] = inputVal;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int monthIndex = 0; monthIndex < eachMonth.length; monthIndex++) 
    {
        if (a[monthIndex] > highest)
            highest = a[monthIndex];
            highestIndex = monthIndex;
        if (a[monthIndex] < lowest)
            lowest = a[monthIndex];
            lowestIndex = monthIndex;
        sum = sum + a[monthIndex];
    }

    totalPrecipitation = sum;

    average = sum / 12;
    feet = (int)totalPrecipitation/12; 
    inches = (int)(totalPrecipitation%12); 

    System.out.println("Precipitation Statistics for " + city + " in " + year + " is:");
    for (int monthCount = 0; monthCount < eachMonth.length; monthCount++) {
        System.out.println(eachMonth[monthCount] + ":" + a[monthCount]);
    }

    System.out.println("The total precipitation for the year was: " + feet + " feet " + inches + " inches ");
    System.out.println("The average monthly precipitation for the year was: " + average + "inches");
    System.out.println("The month with the least amount of precipitation in inches was in " + eachMonth[lowestIndex] + " with " + lowest + " inches");
    System.out.println("The month with the most amount of precipitation in inches was in " + eachMonth[highestIndex] + " with " + highest + " inches");


}



}
```

Comment: Java will save you the trouble of making your own months: `String[] eachMonth = java.text.DateFormatSymbols.getInstance().getMonths();` 

`

Answer (score 0):

Java uses `{}` to wrap blocks of code.

```
    if (a[monthIndex] > highest)
        highest = a[monthIndex];
        highestIndex = monthIndex;
    if (a[monthIndex] < lowest)
        lowest = a[monthIndex];
        lowestIndex = monthIndex;
```

This code is executed in the following way:

```
    if (a[monthIndex] > highest) {
        highest = a[monthIndex];
    }
    highestIndex = monthIndex;
    if (a[monthIndex] < lowest) {
        lowest = a[monthIndex];
    }
    lowestIndex = monthIndex;
```

So to fix the problem you have to specify execution blocks:

```
    if (a[monthIndex] > highest) {
        highest = a[monthIndex];
        highestIndex = monthIndex;
    }
    if (a[monthIndex] < lowest) {
        lowest = a[monthIndex];
        lowestIndex = monthIndex;
    }
```

Comment: I my goodness I skipped right over that. thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion.  Instead of prompting twice for input in case of an error, put the first prompt outside the while loop.  And a slight re-arrangement might make it somewhat simpler (but there is nothing wrong with the way you did it).

```
System.out.println(
        "Enter four digit number between 1900 and 2025 ");
while (true) {
    year = scanner.nextInt();
    if (year >= 1900 && year <= 2025) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(
            "Error invalid input enter number between 1900 and 2025"); 
}
```